# How to add a single letter filter to input box

Tags: javascript, html, input

i would like to be able to type "i" in a input box and get an output of "!", i would like to use more then one letter too [Ex: i = ! | t = 7], and I would like it to be easy to add new letters in the js, the output will have the id of output, like this `<div id="output"></div>` thx, hiiii

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: well nothing, i don't even know were to start, that is why i asked.

Comment: Well start with adding event listeners and reading the text and outputting the text

Comment: OH i got it so add an event listener for "i" and then run function that says document.getelementbyid("output").innerHTML += "!"; right?

Comment: Just in case if you are wondering why you got so many downvotes, Please *do not* ask us to do this for you without showing any efforts or any code attempts. Note that Stackoverflow is **not a free code writing service**, and also do some research before posting anything. It is also recommended to read the [How do i ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [What questions are suitable?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section of Stackoverflow. Goodluck on your journey and :Dhave a great day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet with two input boxes: the top one defining the replacement rules and the bottom one accepting any text input to be processed:

```js
function mkdict(){
 dict={};
 key.value.split(",").forEach(kv=>{
  let [k,v]=kv.split("=");
  dict[k]=v;
 }); transform();
}
  
function transform(){
 out.textContent=text.value.split("").map(c=>dict[c]||c).join("");
}

var dict;
mkdict();
key.addEventListener("input",mkdict);
text.addEventListener("input",transform);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="i=!,t=7" id="key"><br>
<input type="text" id="text">
<div id="out"></div>
```

For the sake of brevity I made use of the fact that DOM elements with `id` attributes are directly visible in the global name space with their `id`. This is not considered good (=sustainable and maintainable) style. Instead you should use something like:

```
const key=document.getElementById("key")
```

Comment: can u make it so that you have to put a = sign in between "i!" ? and a "," after?

Comment: Voilá. Just changed my answer ...

Answer (score 1):

I have added a working demo, you can add more key-value in the `obj`:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
const result = document.querySelector("#result");

const obj = {
  i: "!",
  t: "7",
  7:"t",
  4:"A",
}

input.addEventListener("input", (event)=>{
  const key = event.target.value;
  result.innerText += (obj[key] || key);
  input.value = "";
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<br>
<b>Result:</b>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: could i add a clear button?

Comment: You can just set `result.innerText = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map your letters to output values you could use an object

e.g.

```
const yourObject = { 
  "i": "!", 
  "t": "7" 
};
```

Add an event listener for the input box and run its value through the object to get the mapped output, i.e. yourObject[input.value] which you could then display in your div

Comment: space does not work any help?